# How to initialize the following static variable?

Tags: c++, static-members

I am trying to implement Singleton design pattern in heap data structure but how should I initialize the following static variable called root? Compiler gives me an error

> expected initializer before '*' token

```
class node
{
    public:
    node *lft,*rght;
    static node* root;
    node()
    {
        lft=NULL;
        rght=NULL;
    }
    int val;
}

node* node::root=NULL;
```

Comment: You have a missing `;` after the class declaration.

Comment: How can something like a node be a Singleton? Even the class definition itself acknowledges the existence of multiple instances.

Comment: I got it. I applied singleton in a wrong purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question doesn't really make much sense (A singleton Node?)

You're missing a semicolon after your class definition.

Research singletons, improve your design, and I suggest you create a singleton NodeTree or something if you're dead set on using the singleton design. Nodes should not be singletons, as there will be more than one of them.

Comment: A node tree should not be a Singleton either.

Comment: A particular NodeTree might be a singleton, but I agree that in general they shouldn't be. I used the phrase "dead set" for a reason.

Comment: That's not completely true! There are well defined use cases of using a double linked lists `head` as a Singleton (global variable). E.g. we're doing consciously for keeping a globally accessible list of threads with our OSAL.

Comment: I would do that as a singleton node wrapper, not a singleton node, for clarities sake. Either way it wouldn't be a static member of the node class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I still don't understand how this is a Singleton. It's just a special instance of the same class, isn't it?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I have to admit we're using an intrusiive linked list for the particular case mentioned.